# No GPU Drivers Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: graphics

I installed today Ubuntu 17.10 on a Dell Inspiron 5520.
The only problem I got (a major one) is that the OS won't recognize my GPUs.
The laptop I have has 2 GPUs (Intel one, of course) and an AMD one, but none of them is recognized by the OS.
In the details application I get this:

```
llvmpipe (LLVM 5.0, 256 bits)
```

as my graphics.
To my understanding this is a fallback gpu or something like that.
I tried few things but none worked.
I can't use the laptop like that as it is very glitchy and laggy.

Thanks in advance!